# How to implement a combination search?

Tags: python, sql, logic

I am working on an API endpoint (`Python` + Sqlite) that runs a `SQL` query based on the following parameters: race, gender, age, location. The caveat, however, is that all of these parameters are optional and any combination of the parameters is valid. For example, the following requests are all valid.

```
localhost:8000/api?age=10&gender=M

localhost:8000/api?race=Asian&age=3&location=US&gender=F

localhost:8000/api
```

I'm not sure how to best approach this. It seems like a simple logic puzzle, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. The only difference between all of these would be the "Where" statement in the `SQL` query.

Any advice or related ideas I could look into would be appreciated. Sorry if I didn't explain the problem clearly, I am struggling to even articulate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM (like SQLAlchemy, Peewee, Django and others…)? They allow to do such queries simply but require to model you tables on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is construct the SQL query based on the parameters received in the incoming request.
Simple pseudo code :

```
SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable "
if there are any parameters
    SQLquery = SQLquery + "WHERE "
any more parameters?
   SQLquery = SQLquery + " and "
if input request has age
    SQLquery = SQLquery + "age = " + agevalue
any more parameters?
   SQLquery = SQLquery + " and "
if input request has race 
    SQLquery = SQLquery + "race = " + racevalue   
any more parameters?
   SQLquery = SQLquery + " and "
if input request has gender 
    SQLquery = SQLquery + "gender = " + gendervalue     
any more parameters?
   SQLquery = SQLquery + " and "
if input request has location
    SQLquery = SQLquery + "location = " + locationvalue 
Use SQLquery to fetch data from database
```